# How can I create a function to search for an ID, locate and change one field of this record?

Tags: arrays, search, swiftui

Model:

```
enum TaskType: Int, Codable {
    
    case upcoming = 0
    case inProgress
    case testing
    case completed
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .upcoming:
            return "Upcoming"
        case .inProgress:
            return "In Progress"
        case .testing:
            return "Testing"
        case .completed:
            return "Completed"
        }
    }
}

struct TasksModel: Encodable, Decodable {
    
    var upcomingArray: [TaskInfo]
    var inProgressArray: [TaskInfo]
    var testingArray: [TaskInfo]
    var completedArray: [TaskInfo]
}

struct TaskInfo: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var taskStatus: TaskType
    var taskDate = Date()
}
```

VM:

```
class HomeVM: ObservableObject {
            
      @Published var tasksArray: TasksModel
                    
      self.tasksArray = TasksModel.init(upcomingArray: [], inProgressArray: [], testingArray: [], completedArray: [])
}
```

So now that I could locate the record with received taskID and change the taskStatus, I need also to move the record from upcomingArray to inProgressArray. This is what I’m trying:

```
func inProgressSetTask(taskID: String) {
    @StateObject var viewModel = HomeVM()
    if let index = viewModel.tasksArray.upcomingArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
        
        // Update task status
        
        viewModel.tasksArray.upcomingArray[index].taskStatus = .inProgress
        
        // Need to remove from upcomingArray and append into inProgressArray
        
        viewModel.tasksArray.upcomingArray.remove(at: index)
        
        var lastIndex = viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray.last
        
        viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray[lastIndex].append()
        
        viewModel.save()
        
        // End
        
    } else {
```

…

Updating taskStatus above working fine but remove from one array into another is not.

This code above will repeat for each array after else. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following example code to achieve what you want:
(note, you should have `@StateObject var viewModel = HomeVM()` outside of the `func inProgressSetTask(taskID: String) {...}`
or pass it in as a parameter)

EDIT-1: moving the function with all arrays into `HomeVM` and assuming `id` are unique.

```
func inProgressSetTask(taskID: String) {
    print("InProgress Set ID# \(taskID)")
    
    // with index, using `firstIndex`
    if let index = viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
        // do something with the index
        viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray[index].title = "xxx"
    }
    
    // with TaskInfo, using `first`
    if var taskInfo = viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray.first(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
        // do something with the taskInfo
        taskInfo.title = "xxx"
    }

}
```

With all arrays of TaskInfo, use the function `setTaskFromAll(...)` in `HomeVM`. For example: `viewModel.setTaskFromAll(taskID: "1")`

```
class HomeVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasksArray: TasksModel = TasksModel.init(upcomingArray: [], inProgressArray: [], testingArray: [], completedArray: [])

    func setTaskFromAll(taskID: String) {
        if let index = tasksArray.inProgressArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
            tasksArray.inProgressArray[index].title = "inProgress"
        } else {
            if let index = tasksArray.completedArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
                tasksArray.completedArray[index].title = "completed"
            } else {
                if let index = tasksArray.testingArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
                    tasksArray.testingArray[index].title = "testing"
                } else {
                    if let index = tasksArray.upcomingArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
                        tasksArray.upcomingArray[index].title = "upcoming"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-2:

However, since you  already have the "TaskType" of each array in the `TaskInfo` struct, why not remove `TasksModel`
and use a single array of `TaskInfo` in your `HomeVM`. Like this:

```
class HomeVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasksArray: [TaskInfo] = [
        TaskInfo(id: "1", title: "title1", description: "description1", taskStatus: .upcoming),
        TaskInfo(id: "2", title: "title2", description: "description2", taskStatus: .inProgress)
        // ....
    ]
    
    func setTask(taskID: String, to taskType: TaskType) {
        if let index = tasksArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
            tasksArray[index].taskStatus = taskType
        }
    }

    func getAllTaskInfo(_ oftype: TaskType) -> [TaskInfo] {
        return tasksArray.filter{$0.taskStatus == oftype}
    }
}
```

and use it like this: `viewModel.setTask(taskID: "1", to: .testing)` and `viewModel.getAllTaskInfo(.inProgress)`

EDIT-3: to remove from one array and append to another, using your `TasksModel` scheme, use this:

```
class HomeVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasksArray: TasksModel = TasksModel(upcomingArray: [
        TaskInfo(id: "1", title: "title1", description: "description1", taskStatus: .upcoming),
        TaskInfo(id: "2", title: "title2", description: "description2", taskStatus: .upcoming)
    ], inProgressArray: [
        TaskInfo(id: "3", title: "title3", description: "description3", taskStatus: .inProgress),
        TaskInfo(id: "4", title: "title4", description: "description4", taskStatus: .inProgress)
    ], testingArray: [], completedArray: [])
    
    func inProgressSetTask(taskID: String) {
        if let index = tasksArray.upcomingArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == taskID}) {
            // update task status
            tasksArray.upcomingArray[index].taskStatus = .inProgress
            // get the upcomingArray taskInfo
            let taskInfo = tasksArray.upcomingArray[index]
            // remove from upcomingArray
            tasksArray.upcomingArray.remove(at: index)
            // append to inProgressArray
            tasksArray.inProgressArray.append(taskInfo)
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    
}
```

Use it like this: `viewModel.inProgressSetTask(taskID: "1")`

As you can plainly see, you are much better-off with the `EDIT-2`, you are repeating/duplicating things in `EDIT-3` for no reason. There is no need for separate arrays for the different `TaskType`, you already have this info in the `TaskInfo` `var taskStatus: TaskType`. With `EDIT-2`, use `viewModel.getAllTaskInfo(.inProgress)` to get all `TaskInfo` of a particular type, just like it would be if you used a separate array.

Comment: workingdog, could you please take a look into the updated code based on your response to see if you can help with ?

Comment: updated my answer with your request. I strongly suggest you use `EDIT-2`, it is a lot better than the code you want to use with your `TasksModel` scheme.

Comment: I'll work on your EDIT-2 suggestion carefully because I have some functions of drag and drop which can be impacted but thanks. One point which maybe you could have an idea, if I place the function inside the HomeVM class as you did, the class that contains a function that calls the inProgressSetTask(taskID: String) cannot locate the function. If I place into another place (Utils.swift file for example) using the viewModel as I placed into my question code, it says that it's creating another instance and the saved data does not reflect into the view. Any idea ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you should not have `@StateObject var viewModel = HomeVM()` inside the 
`func inProgressSetTask(...)`.  Pass the `viewModel` as a parameter if you really need it in a specific class. But you should 
not have to do that. Wherever you need to use `inProgressSetTask(...)` for example, you need to have the `viewModel` 
because you need to access the `tasksArray`.
My advice is, read more on how to use `ObservableObject` it is an important concept in SwiftUI, and try using the EDIT-2 code.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to compare a `String` to a `TaskInfo`, because the elements of an `inProgressArray` are of type `TaskInfo`. What you need to do is drill into the array and get to the `.id`. That is simple to do. In the `.first(where:)`, you simply pass a closure of `$0.id == taskID`.

```
    if let index = viewModel.tasksArray.inProgressArray.first(where: { $0.id == taskID } ) {
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was lost into that closure code.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as the correct answer, then.